# Loading choices into choicefield - strange behavior

Tags: django

I have a django form with a choicefield, where I dynamically load some choices into the field:

```
class EntryForm(forms.Form):

    project = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)

        CHOICES2=[]
        for x in Project.objects.all() :
            if user in x.users.all():
                CHOICES2.append((x.name,x.name)) 

        CHOICES1 = [(x.name,x.name) for x in Project.objects.all()]

        print CHOICES2==CHOICES1 #this is True in this case

        self.fields['project']=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES2)
```

The form is loaded into the template with {{form.as_table}}. The form does not show a dropdown for the project field.
Now the strange thing: if I change the last line to:

```
self.fields['project']=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES1)
```

it works, although the print statement of the "=="" comparison returns True  (the lists are purposely the same - this is just for testing). I really have no idea how this can even work technically.

Edit - my project model:

```
class Project(BaseModel):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Comment: Could you please show your `Project` model?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use queryset argument, which is mandatory:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.queryset

ChoiceField must be declared with (queryset=None), and in the `__init__` method you complete the query:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

The problem could be about the execution order of the queries, or the cache of non-lazy queries.

And I agree with little_birdie: the field already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your field named `project` already exists and there's no need to construct another one as you are doing.  It's better to just set the choices on the existing field:

```
self.fields['project'].choices = CHOICES2
```

But maybe you'd be better off using a ModelChoiceField:

```
project = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.none())
```

and then set the queryset you want in **init** like so:

```
self.fields['project'].queryset=Project.objects.filter(users__in=[user])
```

..which should give you a list of all projects associated with `user`.